# Burp Suite change value cookie

Tags: cookies, burp-suite

I'm trying to change the value of a cookie using the Burp option, "Match and Replace". Here is my configuration:

```
Item:    Request header
Match:   cookieName:.*;
Replace: cookieName:myValue;
Type:    Literal.
```

Unfortunately, it does not work with this configuration. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your match-and-replace rule out myself and identified two issues:

1. Based on [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265), the Cookie Header starts with `Cookie:` , followed by `cookieName=cookieValue`. This means your rule `Match: cookieName:.*; Replace: cookieName:myValue;` should instead read `Match: cookieName=.*; Replace: cookieName=myValue;`
2. The type should be Regex instead of Literal

This modified rule worked for me:

```
Item:    Request header
Match:   cookieName=.*;
Replace: cookieName=myValue;
Type:    Regex
```